# Send JSON date to a PHP backend, timezone is lost

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, timezone

I am missing something about dates here.

Assume i have a very basic input page, like this

Markup

```
<input type="date" ng-model="item.date">
<button ng-click="test(item)">Test</button>
```

Angular module

```
angular.module('test', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.test = function(item) {
    $http.post('___', item);
  }
});
```

Then on the server side there's this trivial code.

```
date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Rome' );
var_dump( new \DateTime($input['date']) );
```

being `$input['date']` the post-ed JSON date value, which holds some iso format like the following:

```
2016-03-22T23:00:00.000Z
```

Now, having the timezone set, i would expect the above mentioned ISO date to be properly handled with the correct timezone, but what i see is instead this

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-03-22 23:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
```

which should be resolved instead to 2016-03-23 utc+1.

**tl;dr**

Shouldn't the following code

```
date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Rome' );
var_dump( new \DateTime('2016-03-22T23:00:00.000Z');
```

resolve to 2016-03-23 utc+1 ?

Comment: Two days difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly, but probably not as you intended.

Your Javascript date is generated in the browser, with - I assume - the timezone set as `Europe/Rome` already. If you use a datepicker plugin, you will most probably get the cited date if you pick `2016-03-24`, which will be converted by your browser to the local timezone.
The variable it is stored in itself does not carry any information about the timezone, with the `Z` part of the date string it just assumes it's UTC.

On the server you're just initializing the date with just this date string, and `Z` is used as the timezone. As far as I know, this is no valid timezone code, so UTC is assumed.

You would have to explicitly state in the DateTime constructor which timezone to use for the date, like

```
$date = new DateTime($input['date'], new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
```

You're also gonna have to remove the 'Z' part of the date.

I have put together something to illustrate your problem:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a545a7a87e3ad0f2e6eae1d134147aff30aec29f

```
<?php
//date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Rome' );
$date = new \DateTime("2016-03-23T23:00:00.000", new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
var_dump( $date ); // 2016-03-23 23:00:00.000000
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome');
$date->setTimezone($timezone); 
var_dump(  $date ); // 2016-03-24 00:00:00.000000
```

---

Edit:

Try it with the following code in your HTML:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="item.date" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}">
```

Your date will then be in the form `2016-03-18T00:00:00.000Z`, which you can send to the server as is.

On the server, if you parse it like this, like so

```
$date = new \DateTime("2016-03-18T00:00:00.000Z" );
var_dump( $date );
```

This will output

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-03-18 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
```

which probably will be closer to what you initially wanted to do.

Comment: The browser timezone is set to Rome, but the issue arise when angular is POSTing the date, which is converted to JSON notation - iso format with a zero offset. So client side everything seems to be on place. However, your example works the same way mine does. See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d3dfefa7a5e28a520891b4468d001b50be7c408

Comment: Like I thought, the Z is throwing off the parser. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I can see your point, but i would really like to handle that standard json format, without coding too much custom stuff server side (i.e. an input parser before each controller action).